# The import com.android.internal.util.BuildInfo cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, c++, rom

I'm compiling a ROM and while it is compiling it gives me these errors:

- The import com.android.internal.util.slim cannot be resolved
- BuildInfo cannot be resolved

In the file that it is giving error there is:

```
import com.android.internal.util.slim.BuildInfo;
```

and then

```
    private static int getAdvancedReboot(Context context) {
        int def = BuildInfo.getSlimBuildType().equals(BuildInfo.BUILD_TYPE_UNOFFICIAL) ? 1 : 0;
        return Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ADVANCED_REBOOT, def);
```

I really don't know what to do because I'm only compiling the ROM. I don't know anything about C and C++ language.
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can Check your directory "framework/base/core" if there is the class BuildInfo or not